# How to set focus to the playing field after I have pushed buttons

Tags: qt

This is a tetris.

In Qt Designer I added a new Mani Window.
Then I added a frame widget on to the window and a couple of Push Buttons (New game and Pause). And promoted the frame to QtGlass class.

Then I organized classes:

```
class Field : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
...

class QtGlass : public QFrame {
        Q_OBJECT    
    ...
```

After clicking the buttons I would like to immediately return the fous to my playing field, that is frame.

When I'm inside Field class, I can do this:
widget.frame->setFocus();

But when I click a button I seem to be out of the Field class. I seem to be inside QtGlass as in the Signal/Slot editor I connected the events with QtGlass slots.

Could you help me with setting the focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QFrame doesn't accept focus by default. Add the following line to the constructor of `QtGlass`:

```
setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
```

Also names of your classes should not start with `Q`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921915/should-the-name-of-my-classes-begin-with-q-in-qt).

Comment: Organized this: QtGlass::QtGlass(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent) {
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus); But nothing has changed.

Comment: Where do you do `setFocus`?

Comment: In QtGlass nowhere. Only in Field widget.frame->setFocus();

Comment: More specifically. Do you do it in `QPushButton`'s onclick handler?