# Is there a naming convention for Qt extensions?

Tags: qt, naming-conventions

I want to write a library to extend Qt.

I remember there once was a naming convention that one should add his initials after the "Q" in class names.
So something like this: `QJUMyQtExtension`

However, I can't find that anymore and I have seen a few third party Qt libraries that don't do that.

So the question is:
Does that convention still exist or are there other conventions?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921915/should-the-name-of-my-classes-begin-with-q-in-qt

Comment: IIRC, the convention is that `QClassName` should only be used for classes actually in Qt, not in related libraries.